# MVC5 Workgroups and Users

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm building my first MVC5 application for Azure and have tracked down all the parts and pieces I need to put it together (User accounts, scaffolding, roles, etc) except one.  I need to have users placed in "workgroups" and each user in the workgroup can only see the data associated with that workgroup.  For instance, if I have a simple Cars model, users in workgroupA can add/remove/change cars but only within workgroupA.  Users in workgroupB would not see any of that data at all when they log in.

C# programming isn't an issue for me, just getting familiar with MVC5.  I have previously accomplished this with Django and its built in group management, but need to move to MVC5 and can't seem to find an example that gets me close enough.  Can anyone point me toward the best practices for this?

Comment: You're either looking for multi-tenancy or row-level security and neither are built into Entity Framework nor MVC.

Comment: That's the language I was looking for.  I think I can implement it on my own based on the Google.  Any best practices out there?